# Uninstalling gnu radio companion

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, gnuradio

I have installed gnu radio companion 3.8.2 from source, but accidentally the folder is deleted both from my home and trash. I want to uninstall the GRC now and install it again.but not being able to uninstall as I don't have the source folder in my pc.i am using Ubuntu 18.04 . please help me out to solve this.i will be grateful.

Comment: How do you try to uninstall gnu radio?

Comment: What happens if you just reinstall it the same way that you installed it the first time?